# How do I load properties with Spring when also using Camel?

Tags: java, json, spring, properties, apache-camel

I have a HelloWorld Java project that uses Camel to obtain a Map, and print out its contents in JSON format.  The Map currently has hardcoded values, but I really want to change my code so that it uses Spring to load a sensor.properties file of nested key,value pairs into this Map.

I have another Java project I wrote that only uses Spring, and can load the sensor.properties file just fine into an Arraylist object.

However, when I try to use code from that project to load the sensor.properties in my HelloWorld project I get the following Camel error with a NPE:

```
Returning Map
3310 [hello.world.request.timer] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler      - Failed delivery for exchangeId: 4e984884-df7f-4b82-a977-f5cf4c311814. Exhausted after     delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.SensorGenerator.getSensors(SensorGenerator.java:17)
    at sample.HelloWorld.returnMap(HelloWorld.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:231)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:146)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:138)
org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateProcessor.processNext(DelegateProcessor.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateProcessor.proceed(DelegateProcessor.java:82)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processExchange(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:185)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:151)
    at     org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:89)
    at     org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler.process(DefaultErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:75)
    at     org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processNext(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateProcessor.process(DelegateProcessor.java:48)
    at org.    apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:67)
    at     org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:49)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Is there something I need to add to my applicationContext.xml to tell Camel that Spring will load my sensor.properties?  Do I need to use the Spring integration component specified at http://camel.apache.org/springintegration.html ?

Here is my current ApplicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<context:component-scan base-package="sample" />
<context:annotation-config />

<camel:camelContext id="HelloWorldContext">

    <!-- Add Jackson library to render Java Map into JSON -->
    <camel:dataFormats>
      <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
    </camel:dataFormats>

    <camel:route>
        <!-- sends a request to the hello world JMS queue every 10 seconds -->
        <camel:from
            uri="timer://hello.world.request.timer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000" />
        <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.request?level=INFO?showAll=true" />
        <camel:bean ref="helloWorld" />

        <!-- now print out the map in JSON format -->
        <camel:marshal ref ="jack"/>
        <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        <camel:log message="${body}"/> 

        <!-- now log the message -->
        <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.response?level=INFO?showAll=true" />

    </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
    <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" />
</bean>

<bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
    <property name="queuePrefetch" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="1" />
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
    <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<util:properties id="sensorProperties" location="classpath:/sensor.properties"/>
    <bean class="sample.SensorGenerator">
        <property name="sourceProperties" ref="sensorProperties" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here are the four Java Classes I have (HelloWorldMain.java, HelloWorld.java, Sensor.java, and SensorGenerator.Java):

UPDATED: The issue was that I had a constructor in my HelloWorld.java calling SensorGenerator instead of using @Autowired to let Spring do it.  The answer by Frederic at the bottom shows the old code Constructor.  The @Autowired annotation is shown below in HelloWorld.java:

HelloWorldMain.java:

```
package sample;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class HelloWorldMain {

    // define context to load properties with Spring

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }

}
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
package sample;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.camel.Handler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


/**
 * POJO that returns Hello World string
 *
 */
@Service
public class HelloWorld {

    @AutoWired
    SensorGenerator sensorGenerator;

    @Handler
    public Map<?, ?> returnMap(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Returning Map");
        // get the map of Sensors
        Map<String,String> mySensorMap = sensorGenerator.getSensors();
        // print out the Sensors in the map on the console
        Set keys = mySensorMap.keySet();

        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            String value = (String) mySensorMap.get(key);
            System.out.println("key= " + key + ", value= " + value);
        }
        return mySensorMap;
    }

}
```

Sensor.java (which defines the fields I'm reading from sensor.properties):

```
package sample;

public class Sensor {

    private String make;
    private String makeDataType;
    private String model;
    private String modelDataType;
    private String serialNumber;
    private String serialNumberDataType;
    private String sensorType;
    private String sensorTypeDataType;

    // getters and setters
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getMakeDataType() {
        return makeDataType;
    }
    public void setMakeDataType(String makeDataType) {
        this.makeDataType = makeDataType;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getModelDataType() {
        return modelDataType;
    }
    public void setModelDataType(String modelDataType) {
        this.modelDataType = modelDataType;
    }
    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
    public String getSerialNumberDataType() {
        return serialNumberDataType;
    }
    public void setSerialNumberDataType(String serialNumberDataType) {
        this.serialNumberDataType = serialNumberDataType;
    }
    public String getSensorType() {
        return sensorType;
    }
    public void setSensorType(String sensorType) {
        this.sensorType = sensorType;
    }
    public String getSensorTypeDataType() {
        return sensorTypeDataType;
    }
    public void setSensorTypeDataType(String sensorTypeDataType) {
        this.sensorTypeDataType = sensorTypeDataType;
    }
}
```

SensorGenerator.java (the class where I current hard-code the properties but want to have Spring load them from sensor.properties.  If I comment out the For loop and any lines referencing sourceProperties I can get the map returned with the hard coded values just fine.  That's why I suspect its some sort of Spring/Camel integration issue):

package sample;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SensorGenerator {

    private Properties sourceProperties;

    // variable to increment key number for each sensor
    int sensorNumber = 1;

    // method to inject sensor.properties into a Map using Spring
    Map<String, String> getSensors() {
        Map<String, String> sensorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object key : sourceProperties.keySet()) {

            // Separate out each of the key,value pairs as an entry in the
            // values array
            String[] values = sourceProperties.getProperty((String) key).split(
                    ",");
            System.out.println("values array size= " + values.length);

            // define string buffer that appends sensor number for each sensor's
            // keys.  Ex: sensor1 would have s1make, s1makeDataType, etc.
            StringBuffer sensorNumberStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorNumberStringBuffer.append("s");
            sensorNumberStringBuffer.append(sensorNumber);

            // make and its data type (with sensor number prefix)
            StringBuffer makeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            makeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            makeStringBuffer.append("make");
            StringBuffer makeDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            makeDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            makeDataTypeStringBuffer.append("makeDataType");

            // model and its data type (with sensor number prefix)
            StringBuffer modelStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            modelStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            modelStringBuffer.append("model");
            StringBuffer modelDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            modelDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            modelDataTypeStringBuffer.append("modelDataType");

            // serialNumber and its data type (with sensor number prefix)
            StringBuffer serialNumberStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            serialNumberStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            serialNumberStringBuffer.append("serialNumber");
            StringBuffer serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.append("serialNumberDataType");

            // sensorType and its data type (with sensor number prefix)
            StringBuffer sensorTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            sensorTypeStringBuffer.append("sensorType");
            StringBuffer sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.append("sensorTypeDataType");

            /*
              put all the key,value pairs for this sensor in the sensorMap
            */

            //TODO: Change all the hard coded values below to be elements
            // from the values array once Spring can load spring.properties

            // make and and its data type
            sensorMap.put(makeStringBuffer.toString(), "DummyMake");
            sensorMap.put(makeDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), "String");

            // model and and its data type
            sensorMap.put(modelStringBuffer.toString(), "DummyModel");
            sensorMap.put(modelDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), "String");

            // serialNumber and and its data type
            sensorMap.put(serialNumberStringBuffer.toString(), "1234567890");
            sensorMap.put(serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), "long");

            // sensorType and its data type
            sensorMap.put(sensorTypeStringBuffer.toString(), "DummyType");
            sensorMap.put(sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), "String");

            // increment for next sensor
            sensorNumber++;
        }
        return sensorMap;
    }

    public void setSourceProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.sourceProperties = properties;
    }

}
```

Btw: Line 17 of SensorGenerator.java as mentioned in the stack trace above is:

```
        for (Object key : sourceProperties.keySet()) {
```

Here is an example sensor.properties file:

```
sensor1=DummySensor1:String,SensorModel1:String,1234567890:long,SensorType1:String
sensor2=DummySensor2:String,SensorModel2:String,8675309123:long,SensorType2:String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SensorGenerator is not instantiated by spring but by your code, so the properties can never be set.

```
@Service
public class HelloWorld {

    @Handler
    public Map<?, ?> returnMap(){
        SensorGenerator sensorGenerator = new SensorGenerator();
```

You should have the sensorGenerator be autowired in your HelloWorld service.

Comment: Thanks Frederic.  I figured it was something silly, but after staring at the code for so long I needed someone else to look at it.  I modified my HelloWorld Class to remove the constructor you mentioned, and add in the @Autowired and now it works. :-)

Comment: I modified the HelloWorld class code in my question to include the @Autowired correction.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.